# how to access UI deployed in private EC2 instance to local

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, amazon-ec2, frontend, cloud

I have an webpage(UI) which is hosted in EC2 instance ( In private subnet) and accessible only in RDP (created in the same VPC) using IP address of the instance and port no (IP address:port no.). Now I want to make the webpage public ( anyone can access it )… without opening the ports to public....
Any method to do it...pls help.
For backend services am using network load balancer and API gateway for accessing it locally

Comment: If you don't want to open any ports, how will people be able to access your EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need an [application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html) here. Create an application load balancer in your public subnet and route traffic from the application load balancer to your web UI (EC2 instance in a private subnet). You will also need to point your DNS to the load balancer's FQDN.

Comment: Hi faizan ....I created ALB then I routed traffic to the ec2 instance...then I used ALB Dns....its showing "504 gateway time out error"

Comment: a timeout most of the time refers to an issue with security groups. make sure that your EC2 instance's security group is allowed to receive incoming traffic of your load balancer's security group on correct port.

Comment: I opened all traffic between both ALB & Instance